# Informatica envt' variables

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

Is it possible to get the name of previous task from current task in in particular workflow in informatica?
Is there any environment variable which holds the value of task ran ?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Tasks can be executed in parallel - when the workflow becomes serial again, it is impossible to tell which of the 'parallel' tasks preceded the 'serial' one. Why do you need this information in your workflow?

Comment: I am using name of that task as parameter to trigger another task .. we can access workflow name using "$PMWorkflowname" like that, can we get task name using any envt variable ?

Comment: In our case tasks dont run parallelly

Comment: Are you planning to re-order the tasks in the workflow often? If not, then you can hard-code the parameter values (`Task_A` for Task_B, `Task_B` for Task_C, etc) - not very elegant or flexible but it will do the job.

Comment: Basically wt i wanna create is, a reusable session to send alert message. I need to pass name of the WF & task both. it is simple logic, but we need a name of task which failed to pass it as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Declare a workflow variable (e.g. `$$LAST_SESSION`).
2. Use the *Post-session variable assignment* component (*on success* or *on failure* or both) to store a name of executed session.

   [image: PowerCenter - Post-session variable assignment]
3. Use the `$$LAST_SESSION` value in the reusable alert task.

Comment: Thanks for replying ..

Yeah it is useful for sessions, but wt if the last task is command task ??

Comment: @user2814799 You can place an *Assignment* task after the command task to change the value of the variable. In short, there is not easy way to achieve what you need.